# Passing methods to heredocs

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, heredoc

I need to invoke some code on large amount of hosts through `ssh`.

I tried to use so called `heredocs`.

```
function verifyFiles {
    ...
}

...

ssh user@$server <<-SSH
    cd $DIRECTORY
    verifyFiles
    createSum
    copyFiles
SSH

ssh user@server2 <<-SSH
    cd $DIRECTORY
    verifyFiles
    verifySums
SSH
...
```

Unfortunately functions used this way aren't known on the server side.

Is there an elegant way to use these functions without pasting them into every single `heredoc`?

PS. Code invoking on every host differs a little but uses same set of functions. I would really like to have 1 copy of each method definition in code.

PS2. Of course I don't have to use `heredocs` if there is a better way to invoke this code.

Comment: Please take a minute to think about how this should work. You've defined the function on your local machine but are about to execute it remotely.

Comment: Sure, I did. I understand why it can't work this way. I just have no idea how to achieve my goal an elegant and short way without repeating code.

Comment: seems i misread, you need a way to template code not text, so my previous comment is not appropriate

Comment: another suggestion just pass (through ssh) the bash scripts and THEN call them through ssh remote call (so they will be on the remote machine). Although this is not recommended unless you have absolute access to these remote machines (and can possibly tolerate sth going wrong)

Comment: I'd have to make tons of differing files and copy right file to right remote host. I'd really like to have this in one simple script to, you know, just run it. :)

Comment: Put your code in a script, copy it to the remote host, and then execute it remotely.

Comment: 20 hosts, 20 differing files, 20 copying, 20 invoking. Nah, I'll fold. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a local function `fooX` to remotely execute on each `hostX`, you could define and execute it via `ssh` on the respective host like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo1() {
    echo foo
}

function foo2() {
    echo f0o
}

function remotefn() {
    # echo the function definition:
    type "$1" | tail -n +2
    # echo the function call:
    echo "$1"
}

while read user host fn
do
    # remotely execute function definition and the function itself:
    remotefn "$fn" | ssh "$user"@"$host"
done <<END
user1 host1 foo1
user2 host2 foo2
END
```

Note how the heredoc after the loop flexibly maps functions to users and hosts. `ssh` will read and execute each function definition and function call provided by `remotefn` on the respective host.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
funs='
  foo() { echo "foo"; }
  bar() { local a; for a in "$@"; do echo "$a"; done; }
'
# eval "$funs"  # if you want the functions locally as well
ssh user@$server1 <<-____HERE
    cd $DIRECTORY
    $funs
    foo && bar some args
____HERE
```

Not a particularly happy solution, but I believe it satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Not a very elegant solution cause functions are being hold in a form of string. But, hmmm... everything is wrote just once and it works.

Comment: After thinking I "unaccepted" cause maybe there is a better way to use predefined functions remotely on many hosts.

Comment: You could have a file which you `scp` over and then source, but it doesn't really buy you anything, except if you need more-complicated quoting in the functions (in which case using them as strings will become unwieldy and/or insecure).

Comment: @aerion: There have been 3 different answers so far. Could you provide some detail stating in what way you want your solution to be "better"? E.g. features missing, readability, etc.

Comment: I guess there is no objectively best solution of this problem. All answers have advantages and disadvantages. Therefore it's hard to pick one as "correct".

Answer (score 0):

Since here-documents undergo various expansions, you may achieve your goal with parameter substitution instead of function calls:

```
VERIFYFILES='ls; df'

ssh user@$server <<-SSH
    cd $DIRECTORY
    $VERIFYFILES
SSH
```

Comment: This breaks down when the functions need to access variables or parameters, though, so this is unfortunately of rather limited use.

Comment: Fair enough. But the OP's code doesn't and I'd always go for a low-tech, non-rocket-sciency solution if there is one. :-)